# How to draw on the android Canvas from the native code?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-canvas

I have a lot of drawing code written in C++, and I need to port it to the android, but I want  to avoid from rewriting it on java. All of drawings are primitives - lines, rects, round rects etc, but also need to draw digits and letters.

Answer (score 4):

- Create a Bitmap in Java
- Pass said bitmap to native
- Use `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels` to get pointer to pixels
- Go wild on the pixels using your drawing library of choice
- Unlock pixels and return to Java
- In `onDraw` use `Canvas.drawBitmap` to blit the bitmap onto the device canvas

This will work, provided that you don't need hardware accelerated drawing. [Here](https://github.com/google/skia/tree/9f549358b3ac9f61e78b194e39d6ac6eb322e35e/platform_tools/android/examples/hello_skia_app) is a nice example of drawing to bitmap using the Skia native library and then blitting the result to a Java canvas.

Comment: your link is dead

Comment: The link is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) where you render the whole screen yourself in C/C++

Comment: NativeActivity is available sonce 2.3 version of Android, and, it is more pretty for me to build all interface from java code, and only one graphics draw from C++, so, it is not the fine way.

Comment: Then if it's not a real time game you can pass a Bitmap to the native layer, lock the pixels in there using Bitmap_lockPixels() which will give you a void* to an array of pixels then draw in that array  and  unlock bitmap and use Canvas.drawBitmap to draw it back in Java

Comment: Thank you, I considered this decision, but main problem is how to render font on the plain Bitmap. In this case I need to use 3rd-party library to render fonts

Comment: Well I guess you can file a letter of complaint to Google. They probably just didn't know you have all that C code of yours

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this idea